# ack method works only for first bolt not in other bolts

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have a topology for example composed of 1 spout and 4 bolts

```
spout 1 -> bolt A -> bolt B -> bolt C -> bolt D
```

If some condition not satisfied means in Bolt A we now call this:

```
collector.ack(tuple);
```

It will call the `ack` method in Spout.

If some condition not satisfied means in Bolt B we call the same:

```
collector.ack(tuple);
```

But it not call the `ack` method in Spout. Instead after some time it call `fail` method ?

I dont know why? For first level of bolt `ack` works, but not working for other bolts.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I guess you are basically not acking each bolt that's executed. The rule is simple - each bolt executed must ack the input tuple. Otherwise the spout is not acked and the timeout occurs (hence the fail method is called).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use `BaseBasicBolt`, it won't automatically ack. As a general rule, you should avoid that parent class because acking and failing is really something you want to do yourself.

Based on your deleted comment, it looks like you weren't "anchoring" your tuples. That's an important factor in what's happening here. An anchored tuple is connected to the tuple tree nodes that preceded it. So when in Bolt B you didn't anchor, what happened was you were essentially sending a tuple out without any connection to the data that came in.

If you can stand to lose data, then by all means don't anchor the tuple. For low value data, it might even be preferable, but if you need to ensure that the data will be processed, it has to be anchored `emit(tuple, new Values(...)` otherwise there's just no way for Storm to know when it has to replay a message that failed or timed out.

**Tip**: When you `fail` a tuple, also call `collector.reportError` on the exception that caused it to fail. And yes, you should be aggressively catching errors in the bolts.